# Are interaction plots only useful for fixed effects?

Tags: mixed-model

To test whether you want to add an interaction term to your model, is an interaction plot only useful when both effects are fixed. How do you determine whether to add interactions between random factors and fixed factors?

Comment: Can anyone provide me some insight into this question?

Comment: Any ideas of how to proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that prior knowledge about your factors would guide you to add an interaction term or not, but couldn't you simply run the model with and without the interaction term and use an information criterion (e.g. AIC) to pick the best model?

Comment: +1, this is the right advice. I would think you could use a nested model test, however. The AIC is helpful, but I primarily use it to adjudicate between models w/ different variables that are not nested.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we would like to use model selection method, such as forward selection, backward selection or best set selection (from both ends), and all these methods are based on least square principle. These selection method for factors (variables) are standard procedures included R or SAS, and you can set the criteria as AIC, BIC etc.

And I would say yes, they are used to test the fixed effects. But what you can do is to place all latent effects as random effects and consider it as a new fixed variable for selection or interaction. But remember it would be difficult to explain the interaction between fixed and random effects.